# Anchoring Views together Android

Tags: android

I want to implement view anchoring, I have a Horizontal `ScrollView` which I want to anchor to a button, the button files the screen width, in the `ScrollView` is a `linearlayout` with images, I want the Images to be looking like they are pass on the Button, I want to make something like how a Fab manages to anchor between view except I do not know where to start, Fab has attributes like `app:layout_anchor="@+id/appbar"
 app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"`
which make it very easy to anchor it, I once tried implementing anchoring but on Big screens it was cutting off from the anchor, below is my XML layout

```
<FrameLayout
style="@style/commonListItemStyle"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/transparent">



<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageHolder"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:src="@drawable/clothes"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        app:cardElevation="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView"
        app:cardMaxElevation="2dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">



<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add New Item"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/addNewItem"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    style="?android:buttonBarButtonStyle"
    android:textColor="@color/google_darkblue"
    android:layout_weight="1"
   />


 </LinearLayout>

 </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
 </RelativeLayout>
 </FrameLayout>

 </FrameLayout>
```

So I will give an example of Gem Player here https://android-arsenal.com/details/3/2679  I want the `HorizontalScrollview` to act like the Fab and the Button to act like the red view anchoring the fab, I want when Images are being scrolled within the Horizontal scrollview to look like they are halfway on the Button, I want the user to feel like the image is on the button.

Comment: I think you'll want to expand your question a little further with current layouts you have tried, pictures or diagrams of what you have in mind, etc. You think what you wrote makes sense, but I doubt people here can read minds ;)

Comment: I have edited it, thanks for the heads up

Comment: It's hard to tell without actually testing your layout which seems overly complicated to picture (at least in my mind) but if you want to scroll things, wouldn't a ViewPager be a better fit?

Comment: I could have used a view pager but I am only display 10 images